# Applying a gradient to a shape layer evenly that takes into account the shape of the layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, gradient

When I apply a gradient to a shape layer, the gradient is always applied as a rectangle.

e.g.

[image]

The red rectangle implies the edges of the gradient.

What I'm after is for the gradient to be applied in a way that uses the shape layer for the edges... so the same value will be applied evenly to the left side of the shape and then spread evenly to the right. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in Photoshop. You could use Gradient Meshes in Illustrator, but Photoshop has no equivalent to meshes. You would need to create a gradient *layer*, not style, then use the transform and warp tools in Photoshop to make the layer's shape match your shape.